Why and How to Solve Vim and Gvim Not Listing Content of Specific Folders on Windows 11?
So, I installed Vim 9.1, latest stable version and I'm having some problem in opening a project folder.
What's happening is that when I try to open the folder that contains the .cs file, the Netrw Directory Listing doesn't show up with anything and the application (gVim or Vim) is stuck in that screen.
The Explorer is in an odd state that doesn't have either a ../ nor a ./ line for going back a folder or refreshing the Explorer.

Solved: The folder name can't have symbols and this one had

Could you give the name of the folder such that we can reproduce the problem? It seems to me that this could be a bug in netrw. Maybe you could introduce an issue in the GitHub of the Vim project.

cannot reproduce with latest Vim.
